# Deserializing different data structures with rust serde

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I am trying to deserialize JSON that is received from Web API and has some unnecessarily deep structure.

With `serde`, is it possible to deserialize JSON like:

```
{
    "unnecessarily": {
        "deep": {
            "structure": {
                "data1": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "data2": 0
}
```

to rust struct:

```rust
struct Data {
   data1: usize,
   data2: usize,
}
```

without manually implementing `Deserialize`?

If it is impossible, are there any other suitable crates?

Comment: You can define several structs that mimic the structure of your JSON, then use the [`from`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) tag to convert automatically into the flat struct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [serde's `derive` macro](https://serde.rs/derive.html) to generate implementations of `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Data {
   data1: usize,
   data2: usize,
}
```

If the JSON structure is not known ahead of time, you can deserialize to [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) and work with this

```rust
use serde_json::{Result, Value};
fn example() -> Result<()> {
    let data = r#"
        {
          "unnecessarily": {
            "deep": {
              "structure": {
                "data1": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "data2": 0
        }"#;

    let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    let data1 = v["unnecessarily"]["deep"]["structure"]["data1"].as_i64()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The JSON in my question is simplified and the actual JSON is much more complex, so this approach requires a lot of code like `let data1 = v["unnecessarily"]["deep"]["structure"]["data1"].as_i64()?;` Is there a better way?

Comment: @mkihr_ojisan Well I guess in one or the other way you have to tell your code which path to go to find the data. If you don't write it like `let data1 = v["unnecessarily"]["deep"]["structure"]["data1"].as_i64()?;` you have to write it somewhere else.—I read the suggestion of Russ in a way that you parse generically and then write a wrapper/converter to convert it to your nicer Rust data structures.